# how to use osmfilter to look for tags that are not equal to null (osm map data)

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, osmfilter

looking for things in my osm file with `water!=null` as in a they have a 'water' tag AND 'water' is not null.

I tried this with a simple `--keep="water!=null"`, but the resulting osm filtered file is the same size as the original osm file!  So I'm thinking I've done something wrong.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Two OSM files may have different contents although having the same size. They could be compressed. Better using --diff options or simply counting OSM objects:

```
osmconvert myfile.o5m --out-statistics
```

To get all objects with tags "water" but not "water=null":

```
osmfilter myfile.o5m --keep="water= and water!=null" -o=filtered.o5m
```

Be aware that osmfilter by default includes dependent objects. If this isn't what you want, use --ignore-dependencies option:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/osmfilter#Ignoring_interobject_Dependencies

More information about boolean operators in osmfilter can also be found in OSM Wiki:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/osmfilter#Boolean_Operators